# How to insert value using textfield to get data in sqlite using appcelerator

Tags: sqlite, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I beginner in using appcelerator to develop android apps. I tried to insert data using textfield to retrieve data in sqlite. but if I use example "doc_num.value" with query. I will get error "***[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at test/csv.js:61: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined***"

```
var currentWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var label_export = Ti.UI.createLabel({
color:'#fffdfd',
text: 'Please insert document number to export :',
textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
top: 20, //200
width: 300,
font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontSize:14}
});

currentWin.add(label_export);

var doc_num = Ti.UI.createTextField({
color:'#fffdfd',
top:60,
left:10,
width:'80%',
height:40,
hintText:'Document Number',
keyboardType:Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
borderStyle:Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
currentWin.add(doc_num);


// btn search
var btn_search = Ti.UI.createButton({
title:'Export CSV',
top:55, //355
right:5,
width:'15%',
height:50,
color:'green',
borderRadius:1,
font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:8}

});

btn_search.addEventListener('click',function(e) { 

var db = Ti.Database.install('../products.sqlite','products');
var dbName = db.execute('SELECT doc_num,barcode,    product_name,oum,rack_loc,qty FROM products WHERE doc_num = ?',doc_num.value);
while (dbName.isValidRow()) {

var doc_num = dbName.fieldByName('doc_num');    
var barcode = dbName.fieldByName('barcode');
var product_name = dbName.fieldByName('product_name');
var rack_loc = dbName.fieldByName('rack_loc');
var oum = dbName.fieldByName('oum');
var qty = dbName.fieldByName('qty');
dbName.next();
Ti.API.info(doc_num + ' ' + barcode + ' ' + product_name+' ' + rack_loc +' '+ oum +' '+qty);

}

dbName.close();    
});


currentWin.add(label_warning);

currentWin.add(btn_search);
```

And this my table structure that I use for my database.Database name products and tape name also products

CREATE TABLE products (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, doc_num VARCHAR, product_name VARCHAR, barcode VARCHAR, rack_loc VARCHAR, oum VARCHAR, qty NUMERIC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use this line of code instead of yours:

```
var dbName = db.execute('SELECT doc_num,barcode, product_name,oum,rack_loc,qty FROM products WHERE doc_num = ?', doc_num.value);
```

You cannot concatenate strings in execute method, you will need to standard approach of passing parameters in SQL query using **'?' sign**.

Also note that you cannot do this something like this also:

```
var query = 'select * from products where doc_num = ' + doc_num.value;
```

- This query will fail in case where there are spaces in **doc_num.value**

So the recommended and safest way of passing values to queries is this:

```
var query = 'select * from products where doc_num = ? and someother_condition = ?';
db.execute(query, doc_num.value, someother_value);
```

db.execute method can take any number of parameters starting from 2nd parameter.

Comment: Sorry @prashant-saini. I dont understand the statement for "someother_condition = ?"

Comment: this is just another condition if you want to apply on same table.. I meant to show you how to pass other parameters in same query.. this was a general case to pass query and its parameters

Comment: i see. in this case I only wanted to pass doc_num value after user insert using textfield.

Comment: I use this code   var dbName = db.execute('SELECT doc_num,barcode, product_name,oum,rack_loc,qty FROM products WHERE doc_num = ?', doc_num.value);   -- but still get error "[ERROR] : V8Exception: Exception occurred at test/csv.js:61: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: can you share the proper source code of that controller file?

Your current code seems fine after my answer you used. Also can you try using a different name of textfield variable as you are using same name for the table column itself.

Comment: Sure @prashant-saini I already share source code (above) for the page and database information that I use

Comment: I also have try different name of textfield variable but still get same error

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. I get the answer now :)